# Windows handles for Web browser in Karate same like Selenium

Tags: selenium, karate

I need to identify the parent window/ child window using window handles same like Selenium. Is it possible

Comment: Hmm can window handles mean multiple instance of chrome?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks Karate doesn't generate handles like in Selenium

Comment: of course. karate is NOT selenium. it would be nice if you explained *what* you are actually trying to do with "handles" because it is quite likely you can do it in karate in a much simpler way than selenium. but it is your choice ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Karate's UI testing features, but I imagine [switchPage()](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#switchpage) & [switchFrame()](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#switchframe) would be of use here.

Comment: Staffier - Thanks for your suggestion. I am looking for whether we can get the handles,